# Linux kernel module copy .text segment of process

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm trying to read the code segment of a process accessing the kernel API.
I use the mm_struct to get the first and last address of the code segment of said process.
(ref: http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch14lev1sec1 ). 
Then I try to copy the contents of the address using copy_from_user() function, with the following code:

```
 char code[10];
 unsigned long copy_ans;
 copy_ans = copy_from_user(code, current->mm->start_code, 10); 
 //10 is the number of bytes that should be copied.
```

It dosent seem to realy copy ten bytes, and the value of "code" is always:

> \x7fELF\x02\x01\x01

I'm starting to doubt that this even reads from the address, and not just converts the value of the address to char. I'd be glab if someone could point out the problem for me :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`start_code` is simply the part of the process that was mapped in as code. That may extend past the actual code of the process. In particular, most executables will map in their own file headers (ELF headers) as part of the code segment. That's what you are seeing in your buffer.

Read more bytes and you will eventually start seeing actual code.

Comment: It seems you are correct, I see some more hexa values once i set the read bytes to 2048. Yet I'm still not sure, printk doesnt really work properly in those numbers. I will try to send the data via Netlink later on, and if it's working I will notify and  set your answer as the accepted one. Thanks.